# Running a powershell script from within a webpage with GUI interface

Tags: winforms, xaml, silverlight, powershell, sharepoint

I would like to try and get the XAML interface to my powershell scripts to be displayed within a webpage, with the code running on the client rather then server side, or at least best to the solution as that.

Web development is not my strong point, I am just a techie really.
It strikes me that the company Sharepoint should be ideal.

After leafing through the internet, I can not see no sign of any answer.
Surely it should be possible! I was expecting a mixture of C# \ Silverlight \ WPF \ XAML \ Powershell solutions .

This is the main reason I built the script with XAML rather than WinForms, or am I just dreaming?

Would be great if I could get a yes\no and a basic idea of the technology to use please.

Comment: Have you considered using Powershell Web Access?

Comment: Thanks Adrian R, I took a look at Powershell Web Access, will be interesting to see if it presents the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good link from 'WonderBoy' who explains how to execute Powershell using PHP and IIS, this was the sort of thing I was looking for.

http://theboywonder.co.uk/2012/07/29/executing-powershell-using-php-and-iis/